# What to notice when applying conventional commit and semantic versioning for writing projects

Tags: version-control, versioning

I'm inspired by [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/), and would like to add some more structure elements for writing projects, e.g. documentations or personal or organizational knowledge management system. I'm thinking of these:

- **title:** for changes in project title
- **structure:** for changes in project folder structure
- **fileA/B/C:** for changes in an important file (to avoid to tediously create many submodules for tracking many individual files)

I'm also inspired by [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/), and come up with an idea to semantic versioning the projects. Here is the idea:

Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:

1. MAJOR version when root folder has significant changes
2. MINOR version when 1st-level folders has significant changes
3. PATCH version when 2st-level folders has significant changes

What is significance is up to you. For me, it may be adding or removing a file or folder. Renaming without changing the idea much may be denoted with a letter after (i.e. `3`→`3a`→`3b`). If your root folder's structure is already stable before you apply the versioning, you foresee that it will be stable in a far future, then you can skip the MAJOR version if you want.

This idea can be generalize to any hierarchical structure, not just limited to folder structure. For example, a hierarchical graph.

Is there anything I should notice when applying these ideas?

Comment: FYI, in Git you can add tags with: `git tag -a v1.3 -m "tag label here"`. If you are new with Git, you can start with [Learn Git Branching](https://learngitbranching.js.org/ "Learn Git Branching") and [Picturing Git: Conceptions and Misconceptions - BiTE Interactive](https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ "Picturing Git: Conceptions and Misconceptions - BiTE Interactive"). It really helps me.

Comment: for now I'm writing organizational knowledge project/internal wiki via Obsidian

Comment: Having datatime in the filename is not enough to have a summary of what changes in the files, structures and general intentions. I don't really need to go back to earlier versions or have different branches.

Comment: having summaries of changes outside the file can help you querying it easier. You don't have to open the file. You can diff and blame. You can push to GitHub and make use of actions to build a website or trigger tasks